# Javascript replace

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Hello struggling here guys..

Is it possible to string replace anything between the the first forward slashes with "" but keep the rest?

e.g. var would be

```
string "/anything-here-this-needs-to-be-replaced123/but-keep-this";
```

would end up like this

```
string "/but-keep-this";
```

Hope that made sence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply split it by `/`

```
var str = "/anything-here-this-needs-to-be-replaced123/but-keep-this";
var myarray = str.split('/');
alert('/' . myarray[2]);
```

Comment: This doesn't have the OPs expected output `"/but-keep-this"`, try not to use `.split()` for what `.substring()` was made for :)

Comment: @Nick Craver: It does: http://jsbin.com/ifabe3. And you are right `substring` might be the way to go. OP might consider those with that answer if this doesn't do the trick for what he is trying to do.

Comment: @Sarfraz - `"/but-keep-this" != "but-keep-this"``, my point is you're missing the slash :)

Comment: Ever better than I was expecting +1

Comment: @Nick Craver: hmm got your point, but now it is accepted one, can't do anything about it, however updated for that slash.

Comment: @Webby: If you want to remove the slash with the `lastIndexOf`/`substring` method just add +1 at the result (e.g.: `pos = s.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;`)

Comment: @Webby: If this answer does the trick for you, no problem but i think @Nick Craver/@nico have better solution for the kind of thing you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

```
var s = "/anything-here-this-needs-to-be-replaced123/but-keep-this";

pos = s.lastIndexOf("/");

var s2 = s.substring(pos);

alert(s2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
var string = "/anything-here-this-needs-to-be-replaced123/but-keep-this";
string = string.substring(string.indexOf('/', 1));
```

[You can view a demo here to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/RGvuD/), the [`.indexOf()` method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp) takes an optional second argument, saying where to start the search, just use that with [`.substring()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) here.

If you want to remove **all** leading slashes (unclear from the example), change it up a bit to [`.lastIndexOf()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp) without a start argument, like this:

```
var string = "/anything-here-this-needs-to-be-replaced123/but-keep-this";
string = string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

[You can play with that here](http://jsfiddle.net/RGvuD/1/), the effect is the same for the example, but would be different in the case of more slashes.

Comment: Better using `lastIndexOf` to be sure to get only the last slash (I assume he's parsing paths)

Comment: @nico - I wasn't sure about this (ambiguous example)...I re-read the question and was already adding it when you commented :)